# using ms installer to delete previously installed service and install the new version

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer

I am learning about windows services and i successfully installed it using the msi installer now when i make changes to the onstart() method and build the project i also changed the version number in the properties window of the setup project when i install the service once again it says that the service is already installed.
 
if is use the installutil to uninstall the service and then when i double click on the setup it installs properly. how can i make the setup project unistall the previous version of the service and install the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at MSI installers:
 [How to create a setup project for a Windows Service application in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169)

Regards,

Comment: I have already done all this but my issues is simple i have made some changes to the windows service and then i re compile change the version property of the setup project and then i build now the installation works fine until the point where it says 1001 : Specified service already exist if i uninstall the service from the command prompt using installutil -u the setup works fine i just want the setup to unistall the previous service and install the new one this is not happening can you please help me with it??